# How to handel Htaccess with missing paramiters

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

OK I don't know if I am asking something thats been asked before or not because htaccess makes my brain mush out my ears.

My htaccess currently does this:

```
www.domain.co.uk/index.php?Pram1=Val1&Pram2=Val2
```

becomes

```
www.domain.co.uk/Pram1/Val1/Val2
```

using

```
RewriteRule ^Pram1/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/$ /index.php?Pram1=$1&Pram2=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Huzzar that works BUT when some one goes to:

```
www.domain.co.uk/Pram1/
```

I want it to load like a welcome page.... I know how to handle the PHP but dont know how to get the rewrite to to be kind on the blank prams.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I maybe didn't get your question, but you could do the following:

- Add a new rewrite rule:

  ```
  RewriteRule ^Pram1/$ /index.php?Pram1= [L,QSA]
  ```

This would be the easiest to maintain and the easiest to read. I would go this way.

- Make the other params optional:

  ```
  RewriteRule ^Pram1/(?:([^/]*)/([^/]*)/)$ /index.php?Pram1=$1&Pram2=$2 [L,QSA]
  ```

This should work (I did not test this). Pram1 and Pram2 would both be in the query string and would, in case of www.domain.co.uk/Pram1/ contain an empty string.

But I strongly suggest to use the first version. It might not seem to be too flexible, but it is really easier to maintain.

Comment: Awsome step one worked a treat =D I can't click the up button to give you points though... if anyone else is reading this please up vote for me :)